# Word for people who are presumptuous?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for people who are presumptuous and with the same root as "presumptuous"? Thanks.

Comment: "Presumptard." Oh, wait, I just made that up.

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't one, besides a whole phrase like 'presumptuous person'.

The root word here is *presume*, which could theoretically have an agent form *presumptor*, but I've never heard this word used. Wiktionary only lists *presumption*, *presumptive* and *presumptuous* as words derived from 'presume'.

Comment: I guess you could say "presumer", but that seems to be almost nonexistent in practice.  There's a short story called "[The Presumer](https://books.google.com/books?id=o1isjujFMdMC&lpg=PA80&dq=presumer&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q=presumer&f=false)", about a man who presumes a lot, but that seems to be almost the only instance of it.

Comment: Also interesting, because the question asks about "people" rather than "a person", using *the presumptuous* works if used properly, e.g., *The presumptuous are alarmed, and they may be awakened and redeemed.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Quite true, though that sounds distinctly literary.